# Solve differential equation $y' - \frac{1}{x} y = \exp (-\frac{y}{x})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How to find a particular solution of the following differential equation
>
> $$y' - \frac{1}{x} y = \exp (-\frac{y}{x})$$

I found only the general solution $y = Cx$, where C is some constant.

Comment: You can try WolframAlpha, for solving that kind of things: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+-+%281%2Fx%29*y+%3D+exp%28-y%2Fx%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=zx$, then it becomes a separable differential equation for $z(x)$.
Your solution does not work because the left-hand side is zero.

Answer (score 4):

That solution is not correct. Try substitution $u=\frac{y}{x}$. This would give you

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}x-y}{x^2}
\\\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{du}{dx}+u$$